# Correspondence between type A Nakajima Quiver varieties and weight spaces in the tensor product of fundamental representations of $\mathfrak{gl}(N)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, quiver

In the paper "New Quiver-Like varieties and Lie Superalgebras" by Rimanyi and Rozansky it is claimed that "There is a well-known correspondence between an $A_n$-type framed Nakajima quiver variety and
a weight space in the tensor product of fundamental representations of $\mathfrak{gl}(N)$".

Where can I read about this correspondence, or if it is short enough to explain, can you give a sketch of how it works? I understand the geometry of the subclass of Nakajima quiver varieties as the cotangent bundles to flag varieties, and I can imagine how this might be related to representations of $\mathfrak{gl}(N)$, but I am not sure exactly how and I have no idea for general type $A$ quiver framings.

Comment: Can I ask what do you mean by "general type A"?

Comment: @wood I just mean all of the type A quiver varieties, as opposed to the subclass of cotangent bundles to flag varieties.